# Inspect Event Listeners in Electron

Tags: electron

I would like to inspect Event Listeners in an Electron app.

There is meant to be a plugin for electron that does this:
https://www.electronjs.org/devtron

However it's unmaintained and we're getting [this error](https://github.com/electron-userland/devtron/issues/245)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Does anyone know of an alternative method of inspecting Event Listeners?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: did you added nodeIntegration:true in your cofig . inorder to use node in your code

Comment: Yes I tried that.  Same error.  Does devtron work ok for you?

Comment: OK. i didn't used it, but the error code actually means that the node-integration didn't happen normaly